# How to integrate airbrake my Nodejs project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, airbrake

My project is written with Node and AngularJs, I want integrate Airbrake. I searched a lot, but still can't imagine how. I see ways by do this using node, angular directive, express. Which one I must use? or maybe all together? Can someone explain me whole logic of this and show example. Thanks)

Comment: Have you tried something? Are you using Node or JS lib ?

Comment: @Zooly now I'm using node lib, install it for express using this
`Install the library for Express
Alternatively, the library can be installed manually.
Step 2: Configuration
Our Node library provides an out of the box integration with the Express framework. Just copy this small snippet into your Express 4.x app (Your project ID and project API key have been included):
var airbrake = require('airbrake').createClient(
  'XXXXXX',
  'ccccccccccccccccccccccccc'
);
app.use(airbrake.expressHandler());`

Comment: So, what did you tried?

Comment: For new angular.io projects, they've got a guide: https://airbrake.io/docs/installing-airbrake/installing-airbrake-in-an-angular-app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the same [airbrake-js](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js) library in both applications, since airbrake-js supports Node and browser applications. The README explains more and the [examples directory](https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js/tree/master/examples) is a good place to start: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js

Comment: Correct, node Airbrake is deprecated in favour of Airbrake JS

Comment: @zefer one more question please, it mean that enough to use airbrake for express, it will handle all node errors?

Comment: Hi @Liana. Yes, this example may help: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js/blob/76bd320a9262c18bc9656672b612c4aaf6a981f6/examples/express/app.js#L16 it configures Express to use airbrake-js as an error handler. It catches all errors and sends them to Airbrake: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-js/blob/40467a49ebc03f1b96d8853e86a72e614104fb68/src/instrumentation/express.ts#L4

Comment: @Liana It's a pleasure, we're working on improving these docs to make it easier. Sorry it was confusing and thanks for sharing your questions!

Comment: @zefer the deprecated nodejs library had a method called `handleExceptions()` but I am not seeing that in the new isomorphic library. We use express, plus a few other external services, is there a best practice on reporting other uncaught exceptions?